# optimize mysql query for autocomplete functionality

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sql-like

i'm trying to optimize a query that is used for autocomplete from a field in the database. my current attempt is by using `like` and wild cards, yet the query takes too long even after i added index.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pharma` (
  `ID` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `drug` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL, //index
  `form` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Company` varchar(54) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pharmacology` varchar(96) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=92064 ;

SELECT *
FROM `pharma`
WHERE `drug` LIKE '%PANADOL%' ESCAPE '!'
AND  `drug` LIKE '%500%' ESCAPE '!'
AND  `drug` LIKE '%mg%' ESCAPE '!'
AND  `drug` LIKE '%fc%' ESCAPE '!'
AND  `drug` LIKE '%PANADOL%' ESCAPE '!'
AND  `drug` LIKE '%500%' ESCAPE '!'
AND  `drug` LIKE '%mg%' ESCAPE '!'
ORDER BY (CASE
            when drug LIKE 'PANADOL %' then 1
            when drug LIKE 'PANADOL%' then 2
            when drug LIKE '% PANADOL%'  then 3
            when drug LIKE '%PANADOL%'  then 4
            else 4
            end)
 LIMIT 15; //average excution time 1.7sec;
```

i tried converting table into `MYISAM` for using `fulltext` index, yet i couldn't adjust it to act as efficient search as like. since my users usually type words not in same order as record in database so i need to use a leading `%` which render index useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (drug) AGAINST ('+PANADOL +500 +mg' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

However you will have to [re]build the index after changing ft_min_word_len to 2 in order to catch "mg".

With "+" and "BOOLEAN", it does not matter what order the words are in.  However, "500mg" will not be caught, so you should split that into "500 mg" when you insert it.

Using LIKE and % is miserably slow when the table is big.  Especially since you have multiple LIKEs.

A compromise approach is to use FULLTEXT to find some of the words, then use LIKE to make sure they are spread around correctly.  The FT will be fast and provide much fewer rows to do the LIKE with.  Example:

```
SELECT ... FROM tbl
    WHERE MATCH(drug) AGAINST('+PANADOL' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      AND ... LIKE ...
      AND ... LIKE ...
      ...
    ORDER BY ...;
```

Also, it may be worth it to preform the above query, but it it comes back empty, then assume PANADOL is missing and do a slower LIKE against the rest of the words.  This allows most queries to be "fast", while penalizing those who can't spell the drug right.